# Error: not a class or struct name

Tags: c++, inheritance, conflicting-libraries

I am learning about referencing/ joining different projects together. I have successfully (at least I think I did) included a project into a new one via the Properties window (i.e: adding libraries, including dependencies) but when I created a class that inherits from another class it doesn't recognize it and it tells me "Error: not a class or struct name". What's even more strange is that it recognizes the #include "TestBaseClass.h" and its in here where the class in question resides.

```
 //This is located in another project
 public class MyTestClass
 {
     public void testMethod(){}
 }
 //

 #include <iostream>
 #include "TestClass.h"

 using namespace MainSpace
 {
     class MyMainClass : public MyTestClass{}
 }
```

Comment: Please provide code that demonstrates the problem you are seeing, as well as the exact error messages your tools are giving you.

Comment: From the short code you provided, you are missing a semicolon at the end of your MyTestClass Definition.

Comment: I jut wrote an example

Comment: What you wrote is a strange mix of C++ and Java (or some other similar language). Please post some real C++. And C++ doesn't have "projects". Please describe your problem _exactly_.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove the `public`. It makes no sense on classes. Also add a semicolon and add a colon after the second `public`.

```
class MyTestClass {
public:
    void testMethod() { }
};
```

Next, remove the `using` and again add a semicolon.

```
namespace MainSpace {
    class MyMainClass : public MyTestClass { };
}
```

And today we learned that C++ is not C#.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that, but it still doesn't tell me nothing

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that MyTestClass is not defined at this point. It might appear in the TestClass.h, however I suspect that your include guards are causing the error.